# References to multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have many time series stored in a PostgreSQL database over multiple tables. I would like to create a table 'anomalies' which references to time series with particuliar behaviour, for instance a value that is exceptionally high.

My question is the following: what is the best way to link the entries of 'anomalies' with other tables?

I could create a foreign key in each table referencing to an entry in anomaly, but then it would be not so obvious to go from the anomaly to the entry referencing the anomaly.

The other possibility I see is to store the name of the corresponding table in the entries of anomalies, but it does not seem like a good idea, as the table name might change, or the table might get deleted.

Is there a more elegant solution to do this?

```sql
CREATE TABLE type_1(
  type_1_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  type_1_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  unique(type_1_name)
)
CREATE TABLE type_1_ts(
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  value REAL NOT NULL,
  type_1_id INTEGER REFERENCES type_1(type_1_id) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(type_1_id, date)
)
CREATE TABLE type_2(
  type_2_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  type_2_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  unique(type_2_name)
)
CREATE TABLE type_2_ts(
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  value REAL NOT NULL,
  state INTEGER NOT NULL,
  type_2_id INTEGER REFERENCES type_2(type_2_id) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(type_2_id, date)
)
CREATE TABLE anomalies(
  anomaly_id SERIAL PRIMARY_KEY,
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  property TEXT NOT NULL,
  value REAL NOT NULL,
  -- reference to a table_name and an entry id?
  table_name TEXT
  data_id INEGER
)
```

What I'd like to do at the end is to be able to do:

```
SELECT * FROM ANOMALIES WHERE table_name='type_1',
```

or simply list the data_type corresponding to the entries

Comment: Why not just create a view instead?

Comment: I would also need to add the properties of the anomalies. For instance if the value deviates from from more than n*standard deviation, I need to store the deviation. A view would also need to be created for each table?